# Why aren't authentication and login functions part of the same class in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

In Firebase, authentication happens on a `new Firebase` reference.  But logging in happens on a `new FirebaseAuthClient` reference.

Authenticating a user:

```
var dataRef = new Firebase('some_firebase_url');
dataRef.auth(auth_token, callback_function);
```

Signing a user in:

```
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(dataRef, callback_function);
authClient.login('password', some_email, some_password, function(error, token, user) {...});
```

Why is this?  Wouldn't it make more sense to have all authentication/login/signup functions be part of the same class?  Especially since the class called `FirebaseAuthClient` (notice the *Auth* right there in the middle) doesn't even actually have the authentication method assigned to it?

This is a little confusing to me and I'm hoping some insight can help me understand better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the difference between the two and why they exist on separate classes:

- Firebase.auth() is the "low-level" API that must be called in order to authenticate a Firebase client with the Firebase servers.  You provide it with a valid authentication token, which could come from a variety of sources (you might generate it from your backend server code, you might get it from a 3rd-party auth provider like Singly, etc.).
- FirebaseAuthClient is the API for [Firebase Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html), which is a simple authentication service that comes bundled with Firebase.  It's by far the easiest way to get basic authentication working (using Facebook, Twitter, email/password, etc.).  It's been optimized to integrate seamlessly with the Firebase client and, as such, it hides the details of getting an authentication token and calling Firebase.auth().  But that's what it does under the covers.  You could think of it as a wrapper around Firebase.auth().

So if you're using Simple Login, you only need to use FirebaseAuthClient and can ignore Firebase.auth().  But for people generating their own tokens (e.g. so they can integrate with their existing user database), they'll deal directly with Firebase.auth() instead.

Answer (score 1):

After further reading and thinking, I have realized that although it's still in the documentation, `dataRef.auth` is no longer necessary. Creating a `new FirebaseAuthClient` essentially replaces it.

Before recent changes, `new FirebaseAuthClient` did not take a callback function. To authenticate, you had to call `dataRef.auth`.

Now, when you instantiate a `new FirebaseAuthClient`, the attempt to authenticate happens at that moment.  The information that was previously available to the `dataRef.auth` callback is now available to the new callback that you provide to `new FirebaseAuthClient`.

It is slightly different however.  The `dataRef.auth` version was like this:

```
dataRef.auth(authtoken, function(success) { ... });
```

The `FirebaseAuthClient` version is like this:

```
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(dataRef, function(error, user) { ... });
```

So in the new method of doing things, you don't just get a `success` boolean (which is replaced instead by an `error` object), you also get back a `user` object if the authentication was successful.

Before this change, if a user had authenticated successfully and you wanted to get their information, you would have had to pull it out of localStorage or something.  Now it's just provided for you in the callback, which is a good change.

In addition, the `token` parameter that used to be passed to the `authClient.login` function is now a part of the user data, as `user.firebaseAuthToken`.

Hand-in-hand with this update is the change to how `authClient.login` works.  It no longer takes a callback, and instead fires the callback that was passed to `new FirebaseAuthClient`.

Indeed, that callback seems to be the only callback that you will ever need to set for any `FirebaseAuthClient` function that changes authentication state. Specific `FirebaseAuthClient` functions like login and logout will just change the authentication state, and will rely on that original callback.

Additionally, it seems that you no longer have to keep track of a user's authToken to authenticate them.  It used to be the case that `authClient.login` would call its callback with a `token` param, and then you'd store that token, and use it for `dataRef.auth(token, some_callback)`, but that's no longer necessary, since `dataRef.auth` itself is no longer necessary.

So in summary, to answer the original question, all authentication methods now actually *are* part of the same class - FirebaseAuthClient. `dataRef.auth` is no longer necessary, though it's still in the documentation, which is confusing.

Replace `dataRef.auth` with `new FirebaseAuthClient`, and replace `dataRef.auth` with `authClient.logout` and you should be set.

Any feedback from Firebase staff on the validity of these claims would be much appreciated.

Comment: I posted an answer, explaining the difference but I think you got it all figured out. :-)  As you've noticed, the API has been in significant flux lately and the relationship between the two API's has been changing.  But as of now, Firebase.auth() is completely hidden from you if you're using Simple Login.  Sorry for all the confusion! :-)